# prove that $\sum \sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}\le \sqrt{3(\sum \frac{a}{b})}$

Tags: inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

prove that $$\sum \sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}\le \sqrt{3(\sum \frac{a}{b})}$$ if $a,b,c>0$

I started out by using C-S:$$\sum \sqrt{\frac{2a}{b+c}}\le \sqrt{(2\sum a)(\sum \frac{1}{a+b})}$$ but that didn't help.Similarly i tried using C-S differently but without success.That is all i could do. The trouble i am facing is how to get the $\sum \frac{a}{b}$.Could any one help me to start the inequality.

I have  a feeling that substituition is neccesary

please forgive me if this question is  a duplicate

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}\leq\frac{3}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(3a^4c^2+3a^3b^3+a^4bc-2a^3b^2c-2a^3c^2b-3a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you! I should have proceeded more by my method

Comment: @Quantum Yes, your idea was right. There are another ways to prove the inequality, which you got after using C-S, but I think the full expanding is the best here.

Comment: sir,one more doubt , how were you able to quickly deduce by AM-GM that it is true , did you use Muirheads inequality

Comment: @Quantum For $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^4c^2$ you can not use Murhead because it's cyclic and not symmetric. For the rest you can. It's better for $\sum\limits_{cyc}(3a^4c^2-3a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$ to use AM-GM and for the rest to use Muirhead.

Comment: i see , thanks for the insight

Comment: @Quantum Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca},$$
and
$$\left(\sum \sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}}\right) ^2 \leqslant (a+b+c)\sum \frac{1}{b+c}.$$
Thefore, we need to prove
$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} \leqslant \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}, \quad (1)$$
or
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \leqslant \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{a+b+c}{ab+bc+ca}.$$
Using known inequality $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geqslant \frac 89(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca),$ we will show that
$$\frac{9\left[(a+b+c)^2+ab+bc+ca\right]}{8 (ab+bc+ca)} \leqslant \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca},$$
equivalent to
$$\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)}{8(ab+bc+ca)} \geqslant 0.$$
Done.

**Note.** We can write (1) as
$$\frac{\displaystyle \sum \left(a^3b+ab^3-2a^2bc\right)}{2(ab+bc+ca)(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} = \frac{\displaystyle \sum \left(b^3c+ca^3-a^2bc-ab^2c\right)}{2(ab+bc+ca)(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}=\frac{1}{2(ab+bc+ca)} \sum \frac{c(a-b)^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}.$$

Comment: nice proof would never have thought like that (+1). Also could you expalin how you were able to get the SOS.Did you use any software

Comment: @Quantum See update post =))

Comment: amazing!i liked your proof very much (already upvoted), You are an inequality pro